# Laravel conflicting

Tags: php, laravel, phpbb

I am integrating PHPBB with my Laravel installation and I am having errors because variables are conflicting.

Eg: This page: http://clashdata.tk/search/livesearch?clanname=clans&location=&trophies=0&minmembers=1&maxmembers=50&clanlevel=0

PHPBB is using the Laravel `$request` var instead of the phpBB one.

The line of code is:

```
$script_name = $request->escape($symfony_request->getScriptName(), true);
```

What can I do to fix this? Is there a way I can make Laravel have nothing to do with the /forum directory and totally ignore it with everything?

Comment: Where have you put the `forum/` directory? Is it within `public/` (i.e. `public/forum/`)?

Comment: @samlev no. Just /forum. My laravel installation is also in root. I removed the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

[phpBB uses composer](https://wiki.phpbb.com/PhpBB3.1#Composer), [same as laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation).

If you use the same root folder for both installations, composer will try to autoload classes from both installations, hence the errors.

Please install phpBB and laravel in **their own separate root folders**.

Example:

/html/phpBB/

/html/laravel/

Comment: Please give the full path of both phpBB & laravel installations.

Comment: Laravel is /home/clashdata/public_html.  Phpbb is /home/clashdata/public_html/forum

Comment: Laravel should be: /home/clashdata/public_html/laravel. and phpBB remains the same. If you are on a shared hosting plan, may i suggest you consider renting a server on [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). It will give you more flexibility.

Comment: I am on a VPS already. Can you update your post with the commands and steps I need to do to move laravel to /laravel? Thanks.

Comment: I have laravel now in `/home/clashdata/public_html/public` and forum in `/home/clashdata/public_html/forum` but it still isn't working. I used this `.htaccess` trick: http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/ so that is is still accessible without having to put /public/ in the URL. Still same error though: http://clashdata.tk/search/livesearch?clanname=lol&location=&trophies=0&minmembers=1&maxmembers=50&clanlevel=0

Comment: Go to each of the folder above, and then in command line, type `composer dump-autoload`. If you followed the tutorial above, it means you didn't modify your apache's vhost config to have it point directly to /home/clashdata/public_html/public/public.

Comment: Do I need to use the apache stuff? Will /forum still be accessible then? `composer dump-autoload` didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96212/discussion-between-mysteryos-and-shivam-paw).