# Loading phpBB in Laravel code conflicts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, phpbb3

I am trying to access some of the functions within phpBB from my Laravel application, this is for actions such as adding a user when a registration happens on my main site and autologins.

PhpBB is installed under `/public/forums` and I have updated `.htaccess` to allow it. I am able to access and use it just fine.

I have a helper that was originally constructed for codeigniter but should translate in to the laravel world. I am loading it as a helper by putting it under app, loading it using

```
use App\Helpers\phpBBHelper;
```

and I access the functions as such

```
   $ph = new phpBBHelper();
   $ph->addPhpbb3User('dave','password','dave@dave.com');
```

At the top of my helper I have this constructor

```
public function __construct() {

    // Set the variables scope
    global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $cache, $user, $db, $config, $template, $table_prefix;

    define('IN_PHPBB', TRUE);
    define('FORUM_ROOT_PATH', 'forum/');

    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : FORUM_ROOT_PATH;
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    // Include needed files
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

    // Initialize phpBB user session
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup();

    // Save user data into $_user variable
    $this->_user = $user;   
}
```

When i execute the code I get a server 500 error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getScriptName() on null in
/home/ubuntu/workspace/public/forum/phpbb/session.php on line 50
```

which is this line

```
$script_name = $request->escape($symfony_request->getScriptName(), true);
```

I have found a post on stack overflow that exactly refers to my issue but the resolution of that issue was never posted

[Laravel conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905046/laravel-conflicting)

In that thread it was suggested that because both phpBB and Laravel both use composer it was causing a conflict when loading the classes. I am not sure if that is true.

But Laravel is certainly affecting phpBB when I call the `$user->session_begin();`.

Comment: for session conflict in laravel try SESSION_DRIVER with cookie or memcached in .env

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to not reinvent the wheel and use already coded extension like [lara-auth-bridge](https://github.com/CallMeNP/lara-auth-bridge). The registration is simply inserting the right rows in the right tables, not familiar with phpBB3 in particular, but you could see the changes in the database after a new account is created.

Edit: You can surround the problematic code in `try {} catch {}` block in case that the error is not fatal for the registration itself so the server will not end up with 500.

Comment: I have looked at the lara auth bridge and whilst it does take care of the adding user. The library  I am attempting to use has a great deal more functionality in it. whilst your has propsed a work around it does not answer my original question.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention what library you're trying to use in the question. Could you try to wrap the crashing code in `try {} catch {}` block then? From the code you supplied we can only assume that for some reason `$symfony_request` is null, so you should check out why that variable is not initialized.

Comment: I did mention there was a helpers library I should have made it clearer that the add user function was not the only function I wanted. Apologies. but the problem. as for the symfony_request not being initialized that really is the root of the issue. If I knew why that was not being initialized I would imaging the rest of the solution would work

Answer (score 2):

When two applications had to communicates, I updated the twice. PhpBB is written to be upgradable with extension. You can develop a phpBB extension which is an API to create a new user.

Your new extension uses XML-RPC over HTTP for all communications between your laravel app and the forum system. You define a route which receives informations about the new users and then you analyse the creation process in phpbb. This way is easier because you're inside the phpBB/symfony Framework.

In your laravel application, you have to call the API to start communications.

Comment: HI,I guess this is an alternative but this does not answer my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly indicates that the `symfony_request` object is null. By browsing the source code a bit, I found that that variable (and many others) are expected to exist globally.

It seems like you have to `include` the `phpBB/app.php` file. It creates most of the objects needed.

*update*:

Actually, you are including the `common` file which does most of the initial setup. Maybe just making a global

`$symfony_request = $phpbb_container->get('symfony_request');`

will work. (I can't test it myself now, just throwing ideas)

---

<sup>(If possible, though, I'd try another library. I don't like those globals. Nobody does. It makes tracing stuff and debugging harder, as this question shows)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To be able to get the session request, you have to be sure both the PhpBB forum and your Laravel application use the same kind of cookie :

- Same domain
- Same path
- Same secure flag

Are these settings ok?